# Append a subelement in a XML iteratively

Tags: python, lxml

I have an xml with a structure as follows:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
<vType id="Bus" vClass="ignoring" guiShape="bus" color="cyan"/>
<vehicle id="1.0" type="Bus" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="207358226 206878618#0 206878618#1 206878618#2 206878571 206878624#0 195427225#1 25450515 171767377#0 171767377#1 195427224#0 96336873 96336870"/>
</vehicle>
<vehicle id="2.0" type="Taxi" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="172428613 -25301974#1 -25301974#0 172428582 -172428593 -25301969#5 -25301969#4  -165310768#1 -165310768#0 -45073854#4 -45073854#3 -45073854#0 -32932418#2 172436826#1 172436826#2 172436826#3 172436826#4 172436826#5 172405270#0 24629564 172405301#1 -172405301#1 -24629564 -172405270#0"/>
</vehicle>
<vehicle id="1.1" type="Bus" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="207358226 206878618#0 206878618#1 206878618#2 206878571 206878624#0 195427225#1 25450515 171767377#0 171767377#1 195427224#0 96336873 96336870"/>
</vehicle>
```

There are multiple `vType` elements (ex. Bus, taxi, passenger car etc) and for each `vType`, there are multiple instantantiations of `vehicle` (numbered 1.0, 1.1 etc.) that has the route edges as attributes.

I want to now append the file such that I now have a subelement `stop` under vehicle that specifies the stops as follows

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
<vType id="Bus" vClass="ignoring" guiShape="bus" color="cyan"/>
<vehicle id="1.0" type="Bus" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="207358226 206878618#0 206878618#1 206878618#2 206878571 206878624#0 195427225#1 25450515 171767377#0 171767377#1 195427224#0 96336873 96336870"/>
    <stop lane="207358226" endPos="10" duration="20"/>
    <stop lane="206878618#0" endPos="10" duration="20"/>
    <stop lane="206878618#1" endPos="10" duration="20"/>
    ..........
    ..........
</vehicle>
<vehicle id="2.0" type="Taxi" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="172428613 -25301974#1 -25301974#0 172428582 -172428593 -25301969#5 -25301969#4  -165310768#1 -165310768#0 -45073854#4 -45073854#3 -45073854#0 -32932418#2 172436826#1 172436826#2 172436826#3 172436826#4 172436826#5 172405270#0 24629564 172405301#1 -172405301#1 -24629564 -172405270#0"/>
</vehicle>
<vehicle id="1.1" type="Bus" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="207358226 206878618#0 206878618#1 206878618#2 206878571 206878624#0 195427225#1 25450515 171767377#0 171767377#1 195427224#0 96336873 96336870"/>
    <stop lane="207358226" endPos="10" duration="20"/>
    <stop lane="206878618#0" endPos="10" duration="20"/>
    <stop lane="206878618#1" endPos="10" duration="20"/>
    ..........
    ..........
</vehicle>
```

My initial approach is to iteratively parse the xml and pick up the elements with tag `vehicle` and attribute `Bus`. I then copy the edges into a list `edgesnew`. I then create a subelement iteratively inside a loop under vehicle named `stop`. The code is as follows

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8', recover=True)
routesFileTree = etree.parse('kaiserslautern.rou1.xml', parser)
routesFileRoot = routesFileTree.getroot()
vehicle = routesFileRoot.find('vehicle')
route = etree.SubElement(vehicle, 'route')

for elem in routesFileRoot.iter(tag = 'vehicle'):
if elem.attrib['type'] == 'Bus':
    for subelem in elem.iter(tag = 'route'):
        if subelem.attrib.get('edges'):
            edgesnew = subelem.attrib['edges'].split(' ')
        for edges in range(0,len(edgesnew),3):
            stop = etree.SubElement(vehicle,'stop', lane = stops[edgesnew[edges]], duration = "30")
```

The program executes but my algorithm is wrong as it returns me the following output when I try to print

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
<vType id="Bus" vClass="ignoring" guiShape="bus" color="cyan"/>
<vehicle id="1.0" type="Bus" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="207358226 206878618#0 206878618#1 206878618#2 206878571 206878624#0 195427225#1 25450515 171767377#0 171767377#1 195427224#0 96336873 96336870"/>
<route><stop lane="207358226" duration="30" endPos="10"/><stop lane="206878618#0" duration="30" endPos="10"/><.........../></route></vehicle>
<vehicle id="2.0" type="Taxi" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="172428613 -25301974#1 -25301974#0 172428582 -172428593 -25301969#5 -25301969#4  -165310768#1 -165310768#0 -45073854#4 -45073854#3 -45073854#0 -32932418#2 172436826#1 172436826#2 172436826#3 172436826#4 172436826#5 172405270#0 24629564 172405301#1 -172405301#1 -24629564 -172405270#0"/>
</vehicle>
<vehicle id="1.1" type="Bus" depart="0.00">
    <route edges="207358226 206878618#0 206878618#1 206878618#2 206878571 206878624#0 195427225#1 25450515 171767377#0 171767377#1 195427224#0 96336873 96336870"/>
</vehicle>
```

There are multiple problems in the code..First it only creates a new subelement for one instantiation of the vehicle only. and secondly it creates new `route` element rathat than appending to the existing xml. I have seen that I need to use `element.append` but cant figure out where and how.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Where do `endPos="10" duration="20"` etc.. come from?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the updated code here..
`stop = etree.SubElement(vehicle,'stop', lane = stops[edgesnew[edges]], duration = "30", endPos = "0", duration = "30")`